# Prevent Duplication within loop

Tags: python, arrays, string, list, text

I am running a loop to append sentences in my list (named: text) which contain any (or all of the given tags), however the problem is that I am getting duplicate outputs since the loop is running on all tags one by one for identification.

Is there a way like if there is any tag (of the 3 given) in my sentence, the sentence gets appended? Currently I am getting each output 3 times because of this 'for' loop in tags (see "Current Output") ie a total of 4*3=12 outputs instead of 4.
If you see my "Required Output", the first 3 sentences are there since they contain either or all of the tags and the last shows as "Not found" since it doesn't contain any tag.

My Code:

```
text=[]    
tags=["_NN","_VB","_PRP"]

sentences =['Thanks_NNS sir_VBP','Oh_UH thanks_NNS to_TO remember_VB','Welcome_VB my_UH child_UH',"hi"]


for sentence in sentences:
    for tag in tags:
        if tag in sentence:
            z = sentence.split(",")
            k = " ".join(z)            
            text.append(k)

        else:
            text.append("Not found")
```

Current Output:

```
['Thanks_NNS sir_VBP',
 'Thanks_NNS sir_VBP',
 'Not found',
 'Oh_UH thanks_NNS to_TO remember_VB',
 'Oh_UH thanks_NNS to_TO remember_VB',
 'Not found',
 'Not found',
 'Welcome_VB my_UH child_UH',
 'Not found',
 'Not found',
 'Not found',
 'Not found']
```

Required Output:

```
['Thanks_NNS sir_VBP',
'Oh_UH thanks_NNS to_TO remember_VB',
'Welcome_VB my_UH child_UH',
"Not found"]
```

Comment: Your required output is same as the `sentence` list you initialized, except `'hi'` replaced with `'Not required'`. Is it?

Comment: yes, that is correct, since it doesn't contain any of the above tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code could be simplified by using *list comprehension* with [**`any()`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#any) as:

```
>>> sentences =['Thanks_NNS sir_VBP','Oh_UH thanks_NNS to_TO remember_VB','Welcome_VB my_UH child_UH',"hi"]
>>> tags=["_NN","_VB","_PRP"]
>>> replace_with = "Not found"

>>> [s if any(t in s for t in tags) else replace_with for s in sentences]
['Thanks_NNS sir_VBP', 'Oh_UH thanks_NNS to_TO remember_VB', 'Welcome_VB my_UH child_UH', 'Not found']
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your issue correctly, you want only one answer from your inner loop: Do any of the tags match. Your current code is checking each tag in each sentence, and answering separately for each tag (does *this* tag match).

You can get what you want by using the builtin function `any` on a generator expression:

```
for sentence in sentences:
    if any(tag in sentence for tag in tags):
        z = sentence.split(",")
        k = " ".join(z)            
        text.append(k)
    else:
        text.append("Not found")
```